# Doctrine Remove Issue in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, persist

When I am trying to remove an entity using doctrine it runs a new INSERT statement for the deleted entity.

The setup is like below:

Table 1: file
Table 2: gallery
Table 3: gallery_media

File is a standalone table that tracks uploaded file details. Gallery is also a standalone table that stores information of galleries. gallery_media is a gerund (many-to-many) table associating files with galleries.

Assume that table 1 & 2 has id fields and table 3 has fileId and galleryId fields.

My Doctrine Code is this (I am using Symfony2):

```
$this->em->remove($filentity);
$this->em->flush();
```

Now when I run the code; file entity will be removed and the remove opration will be cascaded meaning that associated gallery_media entries are also deleted. But then suddenly the removed entity reappears in database.

My MySQL log show the below queries are run in given order:

```
START TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM file WHERE id = '126'
commit
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO file (name) VALUES ('someFileName')
UPDATE gallery SET date_updated = '2014-06-10 09:53:38', count_media = 11 WHERE id = 14
```

My complete code is:

```
$this->em->remove($filentity);
$this->em->flush();
$newCount= $galleryEntity->getCountMedia() - 1;
$galleryEntity->setCountMedia($newCount);
$this->em->persist(galleryEntity);
$this->em->flush();
```

I believe that shomehow the entity is not detached after removal. But I am not sure. Maybe entity manager instance is mixed up...

Did anyone encountered a similar issue? If so I'll appreciate some feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: The "gallery_media" table is auto-created by Doctrine because of a Many-to-many asociation between "File" and "Gallery" ?

Comment: Do you have any associated entity in the `__construct()` method maybe, which gets inserted by cascade when you persist a new gallery entity?

Comment: Pete I have manually created all entities. Dan good call :) but no, i don't :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that `$galleryEntity` contains the previously deleted file object. When calling persist, the entity manager sees, that file is not yet persisted (because it was deleted previously) and inserts it. Try looking for `$fileEntity` in your `$galleryEntity` and manually remove it or  `$em->refresh($galleryEntity)` or retrieve the `$galleryEntity` from the entity manager *after* your file was deleted to make sure it isn't "dirty".

Comment: my first guess is the same but until now I am unable to find any traces of fileEntity in albumEntity. still debugging.

Comment: Found it. I was handling GalleryMedia entity couple lines above and when I did flush the update of Gallery Entity, Doctrine was actually mananging GalleryMedia entity as well; and therefore it was managind the removed FileEntity. I fixed the issue by detaching galleryMedia entity `$this->em->detach($galleryMedia)` after I removed fileEntity but before I updated Gallery. So you were right; but I was focusing on the wrong part of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you get the Gallery entity, you also get all the File entities that are linked to it. So Doctrine have the File entity in both places : the File entity itself, and inside the Gallery entity attributes.

When you call `remove($fileEntity)` you only kill the standalone File entity, but it's still into the Gallery attributes. So you have to do something like : 
`$galleryEntity->remove($filentity);`
And then `$this->em->remove($filentity);`